# Handling permission error properly in a script

Tags: shell-script, permissions

I have a script that does the installation of several modules
based on a JSON file describing all the modules.

Looping on each module, I call its install script.

```
# Create install log destination
install_log=install_log/`date -Iseconds | awk -F '+' '{print $1}'`".log"
echo -e "To monitor installation:\ntail -f `pwd`/$install_log"
# Install
./install > $install_log                # <- This file sometimes does not have the x bit
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then # Check install exit code
    echo -e "\n"
    cat $install_log | tail -n 35
    echo -e "\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n~~~ Install of module $module_name failed ~~~\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n"
    exit 1;
fi
```

When the `install` script does not have the x bit,
it will throw a permission error message. 
However, the `$?` test does not capture the error condition,
and the script continues.

How do I make my script stop when this happens?

Comment: The return code (on CentOS) when it's not executable is 126 not 1

Comment: Which shell is running this code?

Comment: @admstg It is on CentOS. I will try with the code 126.

Comment: You should be checking for `if [ $? -ne 0 ];`

Comment: Advice:  Copy the exit code to a variable before performing tests on it.  E.g., `install_result=$?; if [ $install_result -ne 0 ]`.  I have often found myself needing to perform multiple tests on the exit code, and the success/fail of the first test replaces the value in `$?`, so the exit code from the install script is lost.  When it's in a variable, you won't lose it until you assign a new value after invoking the next install script.

Comment: @larsks +1 Sometimes the simplest solution is the best!

Comment: NB: You can check if a file can't be executed with [test(1p)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html): `if [ ! -x install ]; then printf "Install script can't be executed\n" >&2; exit 1; fi`. You can also just add `chmod +x install` before trying to execute it. Third solution is to pass it as argument to the shell, for example: `sh ./install > ...` or `bash ./install > ...` etc.

Comment: Also note that you can pass your script to shellcheck program or https://shellcheck.net for some general recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

#### Literal solution

Instead of

```
./install > $install_log # <- This line sometimes does not have the x bit
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then # Check install exit code
    # ...
    exit 1;
fi
```

you can either:

1. Make use of the general convention of exit status 0 representing success, and the properties of the [`if` conditional construct](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_07) and [`!` reserved word](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02):

```bash
if ! ./install > "$install_log"; then
    # ...
    exit 1
fi
```

if the exact error code is not important, but just the general success or failure of the attempt to execute the script.

2. Otherwise, as suggested by others in the comments, you can save the contents of the variable `$?` and then use it in any way possible:

```bash
./install > "$install_log"
exit_code=$?
if [ $exit_code -eq 126 ]; then
    # ...
    exit 1
fi
```

#### Different approach

However, I think the approach from the question itself needs revising. In the context of an installation script, it might be more beneficial to make the installation succeed. This can be accomplished in several ways, most notably:

1. By prepending `chmod +x install`, setting the execute bit on the file *install*:

```bash
chmod +x install
if ! ./install > "$install_log"; then
    # ...
    exit 1
fi
```

2. By passing the script *./install* as an argument to the user's shell:

```bash
if ! "${SHELL:-/bin/bash}" ./install > "$install_log"; then
    # ...
    exit 1
fi
```

or directly the desired/expected shell:

```bash
if ! bash ./install > "$install_log"; then
    # ...
    exit 1
fi
```